# How can I list the attributes of an object in a python module?

Tags: python, object

For example, in this python module:
https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-python
If I run this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import bigcommerce
import bigcommerce.api

# Bigcommerce credentials and path
BIG_URL = 'store-45eg5.mybigcommerce.com'
BIG_USER = 'henry'
BIG_KEY = 'api_key'

# api object definition
api = bigcommerce.api.BigcommerceApi(host=BIG_URL, basic_auth=(BIG_USER, BIG_KEY))

def create_category(name):
    rp = api.Categories.create(name=name)
    #if rp.status_code == 201:
    print(rp.status_code)
create_category('anothernewtestingcat12345')
```

I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./littletest.py", line 17, in <module>
    create_category('anothernewtestingcat12345')
  File "./littletest.py", line 16, in create_category
    print(rp.status_code)
AttributeError: 'Categories' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

My question is, in this context, is it possible to get a list of the attributes of a given object? Or would I have to refer to the documentation to determine what attributes the Categories object would have?

This question is not specific to the bigcommerce python api, it's a general question about how to determine the attributes of a given object, I've just used the bigcommerce python api as an example.

Comment: try `rp.__dict__` or `dir(rp)`, and you can div into the difference to learn more

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "div into the difference"?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> class Simple:
...   def fun(self):
...     pass
...
>>> dir(Simple)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'fun']
>>> s = Simple()
>>> dir(s)
['__doc__', '__module__', 'fun']
>>> hasattr(s, 'fun')
True
```

Comment: So in my example, would dir(api.Categories) be equivalent to dir(Simple) in your example?